# Count number of columns by row that exceed a value in dataframe

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I am working with a big dataframe in R, and I need to compute by each row, the number of columns that exceed a limit saved in another variable in a dataframe. My dataframe `Base` looks like this (I add `dput()` version in the final side):

```
    ID NT1 NT2 NT3 NT4 NT5 NT6 Limit1 Limit2
1  001   1   1   1  NA  NA  NA      2      3
2  002   2   1   5   4  NA  NA      2      3
3  003   3  NA   1  NA   1  NA      2      3
4  004   3  NA   3  NA   8  NA      2      3
5  005   4   5   1  NA  NA  NA      4      5
6  006   9   9   9  NA  NA   8      8      9
7  007   1   3   5   9  NA  NA      5      4
8  008  NA  NA   6   7   9   8      6      5
9  009   1   1  NA  NA  NA  NA      1      2
10 010   3   4   5   5   5   5      2      2
```

I need to count the columns whose name starts with `NT` and that exceeds the column named `Limit1`. This value has to be saved in another column. The same case is for `Limit2` I have to count the columns that start with `NT` and exceed the value of `Limit2`.Also, the result has to be saved in a new column. I have tried using the next code but it doesn't work:

`Base$Count1=apply(Base[c(2:7,8)],1,function(x) length(which(x>Base[8] & !is.na(x))))`

Moreover, and the important fact, `Base` is a sample of a big dataframe with 200000 rows and 60 columns. For this reason my `apply` tests don't finish or I got error. I would like to get a result like this:

```
    ID NT1 NT2 NT3 NT4 NT5 NT6 Limit1 Limit2 Count1 Count2
1  001   1   1   1  NA  NA  NA      2      3      0      0
2  002   2   1   5   4  NA  NA      2      3      2      2
3  003   3  NA   1  NA   1  NA      2      3      1      0
4  004   3  NA   3  NA   8  NA      2      3      3      1
5  005   4   5   1  NA  NA  NA      4      5      1      0
6  006   9   9   9  NA  NA   8      8      9      3      0
7  007   1   3   5   9  NA  NA      5      4      1      2
8  008  NA  NA   6   7   9   8      6      5      3      4
9  009   1   1  NA  NA  NA  NA      1      2      0      0
10 010   3   4   5   5   5   5      2      2      6      6
```

Where `Count1` saves the number of columns that exceeds `Limit1`, started with `NT` and they aren't `NA`. It is the same for `Count2` but using `Limit2`. The `dput()` version of my datafrmae is the next:

```
Base<-structure(list(ID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", 
"007", "008", "009", "010"), NT1 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9, 1, NA, 
1, 3), NT2 = c(1, 1, NA, NA, 5, 9, 3, NA, 1, 4), NT3 = c(1, 5, 
1, 3, 1, 9, 5, 6, NA, 5), NT4 = c(NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, 7, 
NA, 5), NT5 = c(NA, NA, 1, 8, NA, NA, NA, 9, NA, 5), NT6 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, 8, NA, 5), Limit1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 
5, 6, 1, 2), Limit2 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 9, 4, 5, 2, 2)), .Names = c("ID", 
"NT1", "NT2", "NT3", "NT4", "NT5", "NT6", "Limit1", "Limit2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like

```
Base$Count1 <- rowSums(Base[,grep("^NT", names(Base))] > Base$Limit1, na.rm=T)
Base$Count2 <- rowSums(Base[,grep("^NT", names(Base))] > Base$Limit2, na.rm=T)
```

This produces

```
    ID NT1 NT2 NT3 NT4 NT5 NT6 Limit1 Limit2 Count1 Count2
1  001   1   1   1  NA  NA  NA      2      3      0      0
2  002   2   1   5   4  NA  NA      2      3      2      2
3  003   3  NA   1  NA   1  NA      2      3      1      0
4  004   3  NA   3  NA   8  NA      2      3      3      1
5  005   4   5   1  NA  NA  NA      4      5      1      0
6  006   9   9   9  NA  NA   8      8      9      3      0
7  007   1   3   5   9  NA  NA      5      4      1      2
8  008  NA  NA   6   7   9   8      6      5      3      4
9  009   1   1  NA  NA  NA  NA      1      2      0      0
10 010   3   4   5   5   5   5      2      2      6      6
```

as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a big data frame, I'd suggest you avoid doing this by row, rather just run this the amount of `Limit` columns you have to compare against

```
sapply(grep("Limit", names(df), value = TRUE), 
        function(x) rowSums(df[grepl("^NT", names(df))] > df[, x], 
        na.rm = TRUE))

#    Limit1 Limit2
# 1       0      0
# 2       2      2
# 3       1      0
# 4       3      1
# 5       1      0
# 6       3      0
# 7       1      2
# 8       3      4
# 9       0      0
# 10      6      6
```

If you want to do this using `data.table`, you can update your columns by reference, using

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c("Count1", "Count2") := 
            lapply(grep("Limit", names(df), value = TRUE),
                   function(x) rowSums(.SD[, 
                     grepl("^NT", names(df)), with = FALSE] > 
                     .SD[[x]], na.rm = TRUE))
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is a bit off, and this fixes the problem:

```
apply(Base[c(2:7, 8)],1,function(x) length(which(x>tail(x, 1) & !is.na(x))))
```

Since while applying the function, `x` is the row you are operating on, compare it with `Base[8]` is actually comparing a row with `Base[8]`, and that's where the answer is off.